# Ionic - Can't open PDF file located inside application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I'm developing an Ionic application and I need open 2 PDF files that are stored in app's www folder. I've created a function in controller to open these files:

```
    $scope.abrirPoliticaPrivacidade=function(){
        window.open('/legal/politica_de_privacidade.pdf', '_system', 'location=yes');
    };

    $scope.abrirTermosUso=function(){
        window.open('legal/termos_de_uso.pdf', '_blank', 'location=yes');
    };
```

No matter what I do, the application simply can't open the files. The browser opens a blank page or the external application says that the file don't exists anymore. The path is correct:

> file:///android_asset/www/legal/termos_de_uso.pdf

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As open the files directly from inside app path didn't worked, I decided copy the file to a outside app path:

```
    $scope.abrirPoliticaPrivacidade = function () {
        abrirArquivoPDF('politica_de_privacidade.pdf');
    };

    $scope.abrirTermosUso = function () {
        abrirArquivoPDF('termos_de_uso.pdf');
    };

    function abrirArquivoPDF(arquivo) {
        $cordovaFile.checkFile($window.cordova.file.applicationDirectory, 'www/legal/' + arquivo)
            .then(function () {
                $cordovaFile.copyFile($window.cordova.file.applicationDirectory, 'www/legal/' + arquivo, $window.cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory, arquivo)
                    .then(function () {
                        window.open($window.cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory + arquivo, '_system', 'location=yes');
                    });
            });
    }
```

In short, I copied the pdfs files from **applicationDirectory** to **externalApplicationStorageDirectory**, and then opened the file from this new place.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the cordova plugin called "cordova-plugin-file-opener2"?
Details can be found from two links:

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileOpener2/

https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2

It states that it will open a pdf file with device's default application.

Answer (score 0):

The Android webview can't open PDFs. You could try to use [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/) or use an intent to open the pdf in another app (there are some plugins that do this).

Answer (score 0):

As brevleq mentioned, you need to copy pdf file from applicationDirectory to SDCard. Then open the file from SDCard. You can find a simple example at [ionic local file opening example](https://github.com/happy2share/ionic-android-local-file-open-example).
 Tested for android, needs to check for ios.